# Pandas index comes out as header

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series, append

I built a class to hold multiple time-frames for a time-series analysis. I've implemented the function in an isolated test case, and it passes, but when I go to run the code the header for the DF comes out as the index. Since my index is my time-series, that puts a damper on the whole analysis. Since the function passes by itself I'm sort of at a loss, and I couldn't find any articles on pandas indexes and headers getting mixed up.

The 5 lines of code below the function are the parts inside the data class that adds the new data to the dataframe. I highly doubt that is where the bug is, because that function isn't even triggered before I get the error, but I took '''sort = True''' out at the end just to see and it threw a straight run time so I figure I'd include it. Not trying to spam with unnecessary information, just genuinely lost.

```
    def startData(self,slice):

        for i in self.data.data.keys():
            if i >1:

                #is the leak here? where else could it be?
                self.data.data[i] = pd.DataFrame({'openTime':[pd.to_datetime(slice.index[0])],
                                                  'open':[slice.open[0]],'high':[slice.high[0]],
                                                  'low':[slice.low[0]],'close':[slice.close[0]]}
                                                 ).set_index('openTime')
            else:
                self.data.data[i] = pd.DataFrame({'openTime':pd.to_datetime(slice.index),
                                                  'open':slice.open,'high':slice.high,
                                                  'low':slice.low,'close':slice.close}
                                                 ).set_index('openTime')
###################################################
    dat = pd.DataFrame({'openTime':[slice.index[0]],'open':[slice.open.iloc[0]],
                            'high':[slice.high.max()],'low':[slice.low.min()],
                            'close':[slice.close.iloc[slice.close.size-1]]}
                           ).set_index('openTime')

    self.data[frame] = self.data[frame].append(dat, sort = True)

    ###########################
    slice_columns=['askclose','askhigh','asklow','askopen',
        'bidclose','bidhigh','bidlow','bidopen' ,'close' ,'high' ,'low','open']
```

```
slice_index is the time-series
```

'''
    During the algorithm initialization, the following exception has 
    occurred: ValueError : ('Unknown string format:', 'open')
      at Initialize in main.py:line 45
     :: self.startData(history)
      at startData in main.py:line 99
      at start_data_sub in main.py:line 118
     :: f1 = pd.to_datetime(bar.index[0]) #base/f1 time
     ValueError : ('Unknown string format:', 'open')
'''

This is the error I get when trying to access the first space in the base frame I'm indexing the data off of.

I printed out the index and it looks as such:

'''
    Index(['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'], dtype='object')
'''

It should be a list of time stamps. 
Any help, hints, or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you put an example of what's in `slice`

Comment: I edited it to add a variable with slice's column names. They've floats under them. I knew I was forgetting to look at something. That prompt led to the answer.
When I pass along the slice through another function I use ```pd_var.iloc[ix]```, which pulls out everything from the dataframe, but does not pass along the index as apart of the dataframe.. So pass it along separate, or find a way to include it. Preferably including it would be better, seems less error prone?